# Zabbix trigger for text value

Tags: monitoring, zabbix, eventtrigger

I have created one custom user-parameter which is fetching latest yum updates and data is getting captured properly and if there are no updates then the item will throw 0. Now I am looking for a trigger which generates an alert if there are any updates captured and recover if item returns 0.
I have tried using all the possible triggers but no luck.

**Note** - Item type is Text

**Latest Trigger used** - {10.0.0.5:yumupdate[*].change()}<>0

Above trigger is throwing alert but also getting recovered even when there are new updates available.

[Lastest data Snip](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wqo2v.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simpler solution would be to return an empty string when there are no updates (allowed for text items), then detect that with trigger function: `strlen()>0`.